# Angular 6: problem receiving object and to parse it

Tags: angular, parsing, httpclient

I receive from webAPI

```
return Ok(new List<DomainBO>() { userDomain });
```

I get this object with I stringyfy it:

```
[
  {
    "id": 281,
    "domainName": "MTH",
    "domainTypeId": 2,
    "domainTypeName": "Carrier"
  }
]
```

In my service I get it this way:

```
this.httpClient.get( environment.apiUrl + this.config.getSettings()['cleard']['api']['user']['Domain'], { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'BEARER ' + this.auth.getUserSession().access_token }), responseType: 'json'}).toPromise().then(
      (Domain: any) => {
        console.log(typeof (Domain));
        this.Domain = Domain;
        console.log('domains : ' + Domain + ' this.domainID : ' + this.Domain);
      });
```

and my model class in the Web API is :

```
public class DomainBO
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DomainName { get; set; }

        public int DomainTypeId { get; set; }
        public string DomainTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Why can't I parse it to my angular object?

Thank you girls and boys  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your background is probably from a strongly type language :)

So in TS/JS, there is no deserialiser. There are a few solutions so you can deserialiser but i would avoid them as it is unnecessary.

So when you are doing `this.httpClient.get(url, (response: DomainBO) => {});` this is not instantiating your class.

You need manually instantiate the object yourself:

```
this.httpClient.get(url, (response: any) => {
     this.domain = new Domain(response.id)
});
```

However this still is not an ideal solution, as the `response:any`. What you can do is create an `Interface`:

```
export interface Domain {
    id: string;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
this.httpClient.get(url, (response: Domain) => {
 this.domain = new Domain(response.id)
 console.log('domains : ' + Domain + ' this.domainID);
});
```